# Не работает визульное представление xml разметки в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml, design

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой, из-за которой я уже 3 раза переустанавливал Студию. При сборке проекта никаких ошибок не возникает, но при открытии design-меню для xml файлов я получаю следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На "экране смартфона" в этом меню ничего не отображается, независимо от того какие объекты там расположены.
Я пробывал собирать проект заново - не помогло.
Как я уже говорил полностью удалял Студию, а затем ставил обратно - не помогло.

Что я делаю не так и как мне это исправить?

Comment: на восклицательный знак нажмите он скажет в чем проблема

Answer (score 2):

Нажмите на **API Version in Editor** (выпадающий список со значком Android возле Nexus 5) и выберете API 27.