# в Android Studio не отображается часть Дизайна

Tags: java, android-studio, xml

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В текстовой части есть код, но при добавлении Button или Text не происходит ничего - не добавляются ни кнопки, ни текстовая часть. При эмуляции чаще всего текстовая часть появляется.

Comment: Я новичок и нуб, пожалуйста, если вы знаете решение, объясните на двух пальцах

Comment: Измените в визуальном редакторе [API 28 на API 27](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/857401/177345). Просто  API28 еще не релизное и на данном этапе какие то баги, позже исправят. Менять темы - это не решение проблемы, так как смотреть надо в той теме, которую используете в проекте, а не лишь бы что то показывало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поменяй тему, тогда всё должно появиться. 
Сделать это можно, нажав на кнопку с надписью AppTheme чуть выше дизайна

Comment: Блин, спасибо большое. Не догадался

Comment: сам мозг сломал, когда пытался найти:)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/857401/177345