# Android Studio не показывает предварительный просмотр макета

Tags: android-studio

При создании любого приложения  в (Android Studio 3.1.3) не показывает элементы управления в предварительном просмотре.
Как в windows 10 так и в Ubuntu 
Если поменять тему, они отображаются. А как сделать чтобы при стандартной теме (AppTheme) так работало ?

invalidate caches/restart делал, так же делал rebuild project - не помогло исправить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите ваш файл styles.xml

Comment: <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>

Comment: А какую версию appcompat используете? Посмотрите в build gradle.

Comment: попробуйте над макетом проставить 27 вместо 28

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/857401/177345

Comment: Попробовал. Не показывает.

Comment: Я нашел решение на свой вопрос. Заменил  (com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3) или (com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02) на  com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1 в  build.gradle(Module: App).
Далее - File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart
У меня это работает и в Windows 10 и в Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 1):

Такая же проблема была, вон там видишь написано "AppTheme" рядом с надписью "Nexus" и "28", поменяй apptheme на другое название, внимание, не каждое название подойдет, так что выбери что нибудь из light. И тогда будет тебе счастье.

Comment: Ведь в вопросе рускими словами написано: *"А как сделать чтобы при стандартной теме (AppTheme) так работало ?"*

Comment: Согласен. Я знаю об этом. Я выбрал Light - и показывает.  И при других показвает. Но дожно и при AppTheme показывать.

Comment: Я нашел решение на свой вопрос. Заменил (com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3) или (com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02) на com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1 в build.gradle(Module: App). Далее - File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart У меня это работает и в Windows 10 и в Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: Сегодня я обновил Андроид Студио до версии 3.2.
В новой версии этой проблемы нет.

Comment: да я тоже обновил студию как-только вышла обнова, в последней версии вроде все пофиксили :)